# Unanswered Question contain Answers?

Tags: discussion, support, bug, unanswered-questions

Sorry but i really get to know the process of unanswered tab, which means as soon as i clicked the unanswered tab, all the questions contain more than 100 upvote as first and then least 5000+ pages after i noticed that questions contain answers as well (probably 9+ answers) but still it is in unanswered tab? why is that?

Is something with question and answers not accepted by user consider as unanswered? or question which doesn't have any answers? or they consider both scenario as unanswered?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions?page=1&sort=unanswered

https://stackoverflow.com/questions?page=50178&sort=unanswered

Any suggestion would be great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An answer needs to be upvoted or accepted before we consider the question to be officially *answered*.