# Find in a tag: unanswered questions with score<=0 answers

Tags: support

Is there any way how to find all questions via `Search Q&A` that are:

- from one tag
- the question has no *accepted* answer
- all answers within the question are score<=0

= I want to find all questions that pull the statistic of a tag down with "unanswered", i.e. questions with all answers with [score 0 or less](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297029/5994041). I tried this
`[tag] hasaccepted:no answers:1 is:answer score:0`, but with no good result, because it returns only `score==0`-questions(because `score` targets only questions) with whatever scored answers. That means it'll return even questions that have no impact on the unanswered statistic.

Better way - inside of a tag I choose "unanswered" and click "votes" tab, but there are questions with no answer included too(see in [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251040/5994041)), which I don't want to see, but I can't search within "unanswered/votes" tab. How to do it?

Some api call that can provide links is good to go too.

Comment: I think you want `[tag] hasaccepted:no isanswered:no`

Comment: @Tunaki almost, but thank you, I found the solution with your help :) `[tag] hasaccepted:no isanswered:no answers:1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can live with data that is up to a week old you can use this [SEDE Query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/495897/find-in-a-tag-unanswered-questions-with-score0-answers?tagname=haskell):

```sql
select p.id as [Post Link]
from posts p
inner join posttags pt on pt.postid = p.id
inner join tags t on t.id = pt.tagid
where acceptedanswerid is null -- the question has no accepted answer
and answercount > 0
and t.tagname = ##tagname:string## -- from one tag
and answercount =  
    ( select count(*) 
      from posts a 
      where a.parentid = p.id
      and score <= 0 ) -- all answers within the question are score<=0
```

When run today you'll get the following result for [haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/haskell):

[image: results from SEDE]

Comment: The original idea is to get stuff that slow down your tag's statistics, so the best one is to have real-time results. However if you have a damn big tag with a high rate of unanswered questions, then this might surely is more useful than `[tag] hasaccepted:no isanswered:no answers:1` if you have a team working on that tag as you can easily provide links from the output. Awesome!